# upload videos to youtube in one step php

Tags: php, wordpress, youtube-api

I am using a wordpress frontend form. I want the user to upload video and shall be directly uploaded to youtube account.
I have read API and that is a two way process i.e first step is to enter the title,description,category and tags and then it will be sent to youtube and a secure token is generated and then we use that token to send the uploaded video info..

What i require is a simple one step process so as i can submit the title,description,category,tags and the uploaded video in a single step.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that two steps in one.

Just get title, description and file form user and then do that two steps in sequence in your php script (eg. it can be proxy script with only one task - adding movies).

Comment: am so sorry, missed a line in question. I can not add form tag in my script, i.e I want a script so as i can add video to youtube without using a form tag